# Is this way of naming variable functions acceptable?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, conventions

Is the naming convention an issue? doThis defines unique logic for my_function and calls the f_get or f_put accordingly as required.

Assume variable names will be defined properly. My question is regarding the re-defining of my_function every time in doThis functions.

Is there a better way to refactor this?

```
f_get(..., my_function) {
    axios...(...)
    .then(my_function)
}

f_put(..., my_function) {
    axios...(...)
    .then(my_function)
}

doThis1() {
    my_function = {...}
    f_get(..., my_function)
}

doThis2() {
    my_function = {...}
    f_put(..., my_function)
}

doThis3() {
    my_function = {...}
    f_get(..., my_function)
}
```

Comment: some usage scenarios?

Comment: Just a generic rest call js script. I am asking regarding the coding style/ convention

Comment: JavaScript is a functional language more than procedural one (the further it goes to a bigger extent), the way you deal with it exercises its dark procedural side, which isn't necessarily the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more idiomatic way of doing what you do (postprocessor = my_function):

```
 process({ verb, parameters, postprocessor }) {

        const { handler, postprocessor } = ({
            put: {
                hander: parameters => axios.put(parameters)
            },
            get: {
                hander: parameters => axios.get(parameters)
            }
        })[verb];

        return handler(parameters).then(postprocessor)
    }
```

And then you can curry it like this:

```
const processPostprocessorA = ({ verb, handler }) => process({ verb, parameters, ()=> {/*Postprocessor A logic */}};

processPostprocessorA({ verb: "get", handler: ()=> {...} });
```